# Replacing expectation by Lp norm

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, normed-spaces, expected-value, lipschitz-functions

It is known that for a Lipschitz function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that if $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_n)$ then
$$
\| f(X) - \mathbb{E}f(X)\|_{\psi_2} \leq C \|f\|_{Lip}
$$
where $\| \|_{\psi_2}$ refers to the subgaussian norm (i.e. the smallest constant $C$ such that $\mathbb{E} \exp(X^2/C^2) \leq 2$).  Is it possible to replace the $\mathbb{E}f(X)$ by $(\mathbb{E} f(X)^3)^{1/3}$ and still get a concentration inequality of the same form.

I have no problem replacing the expectation by the median as it is well known that the expectation and median are close for subgaussian random variables.  I would like to prove the same phenomenon for Lp norms.

Comment: How is this norm defined $\| \cdot\|_{\psi_2}$?

Comment: I have defined it in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if your $f$ is nonnegative. Once you have a subgaussian tail, median, mean and $L_p$ norm are all within an additive constant from each other (depending on $p$).

Let $Z = f(X)\geq 0$, what you have is $\|Z-\mathbb{E} Z\|_{\psi_2}\leq C\|f\|_{Lip}$. It then follows that
$$
\|Z-\mathbb{E}Z\|_{p} \leq C'\sqrt{p}\|Z-\mathbb{E} Z\|_{\psi_2}
$$
for some absolute constant $C'$. On the other hand, 
$$
\|Z-\mathbb{E}Z\|_{p} \geq \|Z\|_p - \|\mathbb{E}Z\|_{p} = \|Z\|_p - \mathbb{E} Z.
$$
This implies that
$$
\mathbb{E}Z \leq (\mathbb{E} |Z|^p)^{1/p} \leq \mathbb{E}Z + C'\sqrt{p}\|Z-\mathbb{E} Z\|_{\psi_2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Source of this question is Exercise 5.1.4 from Vershynin's book. I rewrite user58955's solution here in a more digestable form.

Let $Z:=f(X)$

$\|Z-\|Z\|_p\|_{\psi_2}\le \|Z-EZ\|_{\psi_2}+\|EZ-|Z\|_p\|_{\psi_2}\le C\|f\|_{Lip}+C'|EZ-\|Z\|_p|$

But
$|EZ-\|Z\|_p|\le \|EZ-Z\|_p<C''\sqrt{p} \|Z-EZ\|_{\psi_2}<C'C\sqrt{p} \|f\|_{Lip}.$

Plug back should solve the original problem.